# F9 executes selected text in Spyder?

Tags: console, spyder

I am new to Python and Spyder.  According to this [this compilation of shortcuts](http://e-callisto.org/cospar2018/SpyderKeyboardShortcutsEditor.pdf), F9 should execute selected text.  I selected some text in the console and pressed F9, but nothing happens.  Am I understanding the document properly?

I installed Spyder using Anaconda on Windows 7 (about 2 months ago).

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) Did you see your selected text being pasted in our IPython console after pressing F9?

Comment: @Carlos Cordoba: No.  What happens is that I highlight a statement in the console, and when I press `F9`, the highlighting goes away.  Nothing is added at the prompt.  Actually, I'm finding that Ctrl-C followed by Ctrl-V does what I want.  Since that is so easy, I'm beginning to suspect that `F9` wasn't meant to do exactly that.  Is `F9` meant to copy into the console from a pane other than the console?

Comment: You have to highlight text in the editor and press F9 to run code like that. To run some code directly in the console, you only need to press `Enter` or `Shift+Enter`.

Comment: For some reason, neither Enter or Shift-Enter works for me.  When I select a statement a few screens in the console, then press Enter or Shift-enter, nothing happens other than panning the console down to the prompt at the bottom.  I'll try messing around to see what might be amiss.  I find other behaviour that I'm not used to when I select some text, then press Shift in preparation to click elsewhere to extend the selection.  After  Shift, before the 2nd click, the selected text becomes unselected, and the console focus shifts down to the bottom most prompt.

Comment: It seems you don't undertand how the console works. To execute a previous command you need to navigate the console's history with the Up and Down keyboard arrows. then press `Enter` or `Shift+Enter` on the selected command.